# C# Comparing 2 lists using Except doesn't give expected result

Tags: c#, .net

So I have 2 lists:

```
...
List1= new ObservableCollection<Article>();
var List2= new List<Article>();
```

**I want to get the one object that is different in my 2 lists**. So in **list 1** there is ALWAYS 1 item that is different **or** you can only find it in this list. I want to compare list1 and list 2 and get that item.
So:

- That item can be an item that is only in list1 is not in list2, see example 1.
- That item can be an item that has a different quantity than list2, see example 2.

Example 1:

```
List1= new ObservableCollection<Article>();
var List2= new List<Article>();

List1.Add(new Article(1, "Cola", "1 x"));  
List1.Add(new Article(2, "Ice tea", "1 x"));  
List2.Add(new Article(1, "Cola", "1 x"));  

//Now I want to only get the ice tea back, that is the only difference in my 2 lists.
```

Example 2:

```
List1= new ObservableCollection<Article>();
var List2= new List<Article>();

List1.Add(new Article(1, "Cola", "1 x"));  
List1.Add(new Article(2, "Ice tea", "2 x"));  
List2.Add(new Article(1, "Cola", "1 x"));  
List2.Add(new Article(2, "Ice tea", "1 x"));  

//Now I want to only get the ice tea back with "2 x" fromlist 1, that is the only difference in my 2 lists.
```

I made the following solution but this doesnt work, anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
var OldArticles = List1;
var Newarticles = List2;
var PressedItem = OldArticles.Except(Newarticles).ToList();
```

Comment: Have you created an `Add` extension method?

Comment: Your code doesnt compile since you dont add items to the `ObservableCollection<T>` in this way: `List1.Add(1, "Cola", "1 x"); `. Apart from that, if you dont override `Equals`+`GetHashCode` in `MyCollection` you will not get the expected result.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay nope, did not

Comment: @TimSchmelter welp for stack overflow I only provided the necessary code. When I run my app, the code compiles. Via breakpoints, I can see List1 with 1 cola and 1 ice tea, and list 2 with 1 cola (example 1)

Comment: @Emmma: [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.add?view=net-6.0#system-collections-objectmodel-collection-1-add(-0)) takes the instance of `T` and adds it to the end. You are using it like it could take several parameters.

Comment: `Add(T)` only accepts one argument, you are passing 3

Comment: @TimSchmelter  Edited it, I was a bit too quick with writing the code here

Comment: @Jason edited it, I was a bit too quick with writing the code here

Comment: @Emmma: now you just need to change `MyCollection` to `Article`

Comment: `Article` should implement `IEquatable` interface.

Comment: LINQ does not know how to compare two instances of `Article`, you have to provide an operator that does it, as @LeiYang suggests

Comment: Aha oke I will try that @Jason

Comment: @LeiYang ah thanks I will research a bitmore about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all methods which have to compare something you need to remember that your custom class has to `override` `Equals` and `GetHashCode` meaningfully. It's good practise to implement both methods in general but absolutely necessary if you use a set based method like `Enumerable.Except` which uses first `GetHashCode` and then `Equals`.

Another approach is to implement `IEquatable<Article>` in your class and implement `Equals` (and `GetHashCode`). It's good practise to do both at the same time(look below).

A third option is to implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<Article>` which implements `Equals` and `GetHashCode` meaningfully. You can use an instance of it in the overload of many LINQ methods like [`Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-except-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-0)))). Use this if you don't want to change how articles are compared in general but only for this case. So you can have multiple ways to compare articles.

Presuming there is an identifier like `Id`:

```
public class Article: IEquatable<Article>
{
    // ...
    public int Id { get; }
    
    public bool Equals(Article other)
    {
        return other?.Id == Id;
    }
    
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return Equals(other as Article);
    }
    
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Enumerable.Except Method returns the members of the first list that don't appear in the second list.

In your case, the 2 lists have no common element, because the elements are reference type and their references are different in 1st list compared to 2nd list although their values are the same.

Use Enumerable.Except either to compare value types or use references when you Add elements in your list rather than Add(new Article(1, "Cola", "1 x"))

The following works:

```
// create elements
Article a1 = new Article(1, "Cola", "1 x");
Article a2 = new Article(2, "Ice tea", "1 x");
Article a3 = new Article(2, "Ice tea", "2 x");

// Example 1
List1.Add(a1);
List1.Add(a2);
List2.Add(a1);
var PressedItems = List1.Except(List2).ToList();

// Example 2
List1.Add(a1);
List1.Add(a3);
List2.Add(a1);
List2.Add(a2);
PressedItems = List1.Except(List2).ToList();
```